# Linq to sql conduct pre and post actions on submit in C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How do you get Linq to Sql to do pre and post actions beside just updating the records? I'm trying to setup a type 4 slowly changing dimension as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_0).

**tbl_emplyees**

```
Id     Name     HourlyWage
--------------------------
1      Bob      30
2      Dan      20
```

**tbl_emplyees_history**

```
Id     CreatedDate      Name     HourlyWage
----------------------------------------------
1      4/2/2012         Bob      10
1      4/3/2012         Bob      20
2      2/2/2012         Dan      10
```

So, what I'd need to happen is, before any records are updated, they need to be copied into a history table.

I looked into stored procedures, but there seems to be a disconnect there. Linq is brilliant that it can submit modified records automagically but there doesn't appear to be a way to pass all modified records into a stored procedure that achieves parity and allows pre and post actions with the same ease.

Comment: This change tracking must be in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "Disconnect" are you seeing with stored procs? LINQ to SQL has pretty good support for stored procs.

Alternatively, have you considered triggers for the auditing?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but when using linq to sql you make your changes to the IEnumerable<T> and Update the DataContext. The round about way with stored procedures is, you call myDataContext.MyStoredProcedure() but you have to pass each parameter individually like myDataContext.MyStoredProcedure(id, name, etc, etc, etc, etc) AND it takes in only one entry so you have to iterate through your Ts and call the stored procedure with all the parameters. And even then you'll have to check if the record is updated or not. Seems to be quite a disconnect there.

Comment: Triggers are perfect! My data structure is kinda complicated so having a choke point for which all update logic goes through allows the history table to always get updated.

Comment: You can use stored procs instead of the runtime generated Insert/Update/Delete methods as long as the sproc uses the expected signature for the parameters. Calling Context.SubmitChanges will then determine if the table to be updated uses the runtime generated value or the sproc and call the appropriate implementation internally. Map the sprocs to methods and then change the appropriate "Default Methods" properties on the tables as necessary or see chapter 8 of LINQ in Action ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this programmatically, could you insert a new row into tbl_employees_history before you update the corresponding row in tbl_employees?